# What is this image that Google code provides?

Tags: checksum, google-code

Google Code provides a barcode like this:

[image: Sample Bar Code]

When you download software. What is its purpose <strike>(I assume it is related to the SHA1 checksum, but if so, how is it used)</strike>?

Edit: Now that I know its name, I found [this article](http://techcrunch.com/2010/04/07/google-continues-to-embrace-qr-codes-integrates-them-into-its-url-shortener/). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code) and encodes a small amount of data - typically a URL. You can scan them for example using a phone and then visit the URL.

[Update: it's a URL for downloading [msysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/).]

Answer (score 4):

This is a [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code), frequently used for entering URLs into mobile phones. It can be helpful if someone posts software that could be installed, say, on an Android phone; instead of manually entering the URL on the phone keyboard, you can just use an app like [Barcode Scanner](http://www.androidtapp.com/barcode-scanner/) from the open source [ZXing project](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) to easily scan it in.

If you're not trying to download something directly onto your phone, it's probably not all that useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 2-Dimensional Barcode. There's software out there that can scan it.